# Custom HTML in Jade Template

Tags: node.js, pug

I'd like to accomplish something in jade, but not sure on the best approach. I want to have several product pages on a website, and most of these product pages will have the same layout and design, so I'm going to create one jade template. However, I would love to be able to insert some custom HTML for a couple of product pages in particular.

Can I use an include or something to optionally add custom HTML?

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically removes the word "Hi" from the top of my question. Chill out, this is a community, we're allowed some pleasantries aren't we?

Comment: I don't think it's automatic.  Someone took it out. Don't be angry though, folks earn points by removing your Hi!

Comment: What do you mean by custom markup, something like angular directives.

Comment: I just edited it to put it back, and it's not there. I'm certainly not angry. I'm one guy on SO, and not super active, so it's hardly my community.

Comment: By Custom markup I mean I'd like to insert an HTML table or an image where I would normally have space for a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jade partials to show different snippets depending on some conditions in the templating context:

```
if user.description
    !=partial(template name[, options])
```

Or you might use template inheritance and render a different template depending on the same conditional, but this time in your controller.  I would probably do the latter.

Comment: Question for you : ) If some of my "objects" have a block of text as a value of user.description and others have a block of html. Rather than store HTML in my database, can I store a reference to that HTML in my database (even better, can I store a reference to a jade partial)? And then, how would I alter the code above to deal with both possibilities smoothly?

Comment: I should add, this won't be HTML that users are adding. It is likely to be my website's individual product pages, where most of our products will have a single paragraph description, but some will require a diagram users might interact with. So, they'll need HTML with a reference to JavaScript and some CSS instead of just a paragraph.